# Search for a string in an unsorted binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am unsure as to what I need to do to search for a string stored in a binary tree.  I have the search method written but I don't quite understand what to pass it.  I need to search for the string before adding it to the tree.  If it is found, I just need to increase the counter within the node object rather than adding a new one.  The tree is unsorted by the way.

My question is how do I search for it before adding it?

```
System.out.println("Enter string to be stored");
stringValue = k.nextLine();
if (theString.isEmpty() == true) {
    node.add(stringValue, count);
} else {
    // I am not sure what to do here
    // How do I send the string to my search method?
    stringValue.treeSearch();
}
```

---

```
public Node treeSearch(String s, TreeNode root){

    if(root.toString().equals(s)){

        return root;
    }
    if(left != null){

        left.treeSearch(s, root.left);
        if(root.toString().equals(s)){
            return root;
        }
    }
    if(right != null){

        right.treeSearch(s, root.right);
        if(root.toString().equals(s)){
            return root;
        }
    }else{
          return null;
            }
}
```

---

I update the search method to this.

```
 public Node treeSearch(String s, Node root){

 if(root.toString().equals(s)){

    return root;
    }
    if(left != null){

       left.treeSearch(s, root.left);
       return root;
    }
    if(right != null){

      right.treeSearch(s, root.right);
          return root;
    }else{
         return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're looking for a String, so pass the method the String you're looking for. Where is your `treeSearch()` method implemented?

Comment: According to the signature of your `treeSearch` method you need to pass `String` to search for and `Node` object for the root of your tree.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the the way you search the left and right subtrees.  For example:

```
if (left != null) {
    left.treeSearch(s, root.left);
    if (root.toString().equals(s)) {
        return root;
    }
}
```

So ... you search the left subtree, but ignore the result of the search and compare `s` against `root` ... again.

The same pattern is repeated for the right subtree.

(Since this smells like a "learning exercise", I'll leave you to figure out the fix.)

---

Having said that, if you don't order the elements of a binary tree, it is pretty much useless as a data structure.  You would be better off storing the elements in a list or array.  (The complexity of your `treeSearch` is `O(N)` ... just like searching a list or array.)

Comment: No.  Not right.  The searchTree method is supposed to return the node containing the element you found ... And you did a **BAD THING** by editing the question like that.  Now most people won't know what your original question was about.

Comment: So are you saying that it should return the node each time no matter what and that I should do the comparison elsewhere?

Comment: Your comment is unclear.  But I'm pretty sure that is not what I am saying.

Comment: Where should I make the comparison?  I am searching for a specific string so how do I know if the method finds it?  What I thought I had is this:  If the root is the string return the root.  If the left if not empty search it and if the root equals the string,  return it. And the same goes for the right side.  The updated method I posted seems to search and return every node.  Where should I do the comparison to see if the string I am searching for is equal to the one that is currently being searched?

Comment: OK, answer this.  If your search of `root.left` subtree succeeds, do you want to return the node you found in the subtree *OR* do you want to return `root`?

Comment: I want to return the node in the subtree.  So would I do return left?

Comment: @RaymondG - Think about it.  That was the point of my question to you.

Comment: I am thinking about it or at least trying to.  This is something very new to me and I don't quite understand it just yet.